# Java Android - Radio Button not showing

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I have create two radio buttons:

- First, for Bluetooth
- Second, for RS232

But my application shows only one of them.

This is my code :

```
final RadioButton Bluetooth = new RadioButton(this);
Bluetooth.setId(TEXT_ID);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(Bluetooth);
Bluetooth.setText("Bluetooth");
Bluetooth.setTextSize(20);

final RadioButton RS232 = new RadioButton(this);
RS232.setId(TEXT_ID);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(RS232);
RS232.setText("RS232");
RS232.setTextSize(20);
```

Comment: Please also share your layout xml!

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have XML. The aim, it's to add two RadioButton, in a alertdialog. The alertdialog is display when the user click on item menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to define your alert dialog.
Creatre a a xml layout containing two radio buttons and then in java make view and inflathat view in your alert dialog.

```
                View view2 = View.inflate(MyActivity.this, R.layout.radiobutton, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder builderconversion = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);
                //builder1.setMessage("Radio Message");
                builderconversion.setView(view2);
                builderconversion.setCancelable(true);
                builderconversion.setPositiveButton("CLOSE",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                //Methods and functions
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog alertconversion = builderconversion.create();
                alertconversion.show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will create a new XML file in layout directory. And I will see, if it's work.